# Regex to match 'lol' to 'lolllll' and 'omg' to 'omggg', etc

Tags: python, regex, string-matching

Hey there, I love regular expressions, but I'm just not good at them at all.

I have a list of some 400 shortened words such as lol, omg, lmao...etc.  Whenever someone types one of these shortened words, it is replaced with its English counterpart ([laughter], or something to that effect).  Anyway, people are annoying and type these short-hand words with the last letter(s) repeated x number of times.

examples:
omg -> omgggg, lol -> lollll, haha -> hahahaha, lol -> lololol

I was wondering if anyone could hand me the regex (in Python, preferably) to deal with this?

Thanks all.

(It's a Twitter-related project for topic identification if anyone's curious.  If someone tweets "Let's go shoot some hoops", how do you know the tweet is about basketball, etc)

Comment: But how will you deal with words that legitimately end with repeating letters?

Comment: You would need a regex for each word in your list.

Comment: So, you're mangling what people type in a preposterous way, and you're looking for help in order to mangle it even more?  That's *fantastic*.

Comment: Looks like someone is trying to find out who his girl friend enjoys talking to the most, by running a regex over her chat logs ;)

Comment: @Hasan Khan: Or her tweets :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**FIRST APPROACH -**

Well, using regular expression(s) you could do like so -

```
import re
re.sub('g+', 'g', 'omgggg')
re.sub('l+', 'l', 'lollll')
```

etc.

Let me point out that using regular expressions is a very fragile & basic approach to dealing with this problem. You could so easily get strings from users which will break the above regular expressions. What I am trying to say is that this approach requires lot of maintenance in terms of observing the patterns of mistakes the users make & then creating case specific regular expressions for them.

**SECOND APPROACH -**

Instead have you considered using `difflib` module? It's a module with helpers for computing deltas between objects. Of particular importance here for you is `SequenceMatcher`. To paraphrase from [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html)-

> SequenceMatcher is a flexible class
>   for comparing pairs of sequences of
>   any type, so long as the sequence
>   elements are hashable. SequenceMatcher
>   tries to compute a "human-friendly
>   diff" between two sequences. The
>   fundamental notion is the longest
>   *contiguous* & junk-free matching subsequence.

```
import difflib as dl
x   = dl.SequenceMatcher(lambda x : x == ' ', "omg", "omgggg")
y   = dl.SequenceMatcher(lambda x : x == ' ', "omgggg","omg")
avg = (x.ratio()+y.ratio())/2.0
if avg>= 0.6: 
    print 'Match!'
else:
    print 'Sorry!'
```

According to documentation, any ratio() over 0.6 is a close match. You might need to explore tweak the ratio for your data needs. If you need more stricter matching I found any value over 0.8 serves well.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
\b(?=lol)\S*(\S+)(?<=\blol)\1*\b
```

(replace `lol` with `omg`, `haha` etc.)

This will match `lol`, `lololol`, `lollll`, `lollollol` etc. but fail `lolo`, `lollllo`, `lolly` and so on.

The rules:

1. Match the word `lol` completely.
2. Then allow any repetition of one or more characters at the end of the word (i. e. `l`, `ol` or `lol`)

So `\b(?=zomg)\S*(\S+)(?<=\bzomg)\1*\b` will match `zomg`, `zomggg`, `zomgmgmg`, `zomgomgomg` etc.

In Python, with comments:

```
result = re.sub(
    r"""(?ix)\b    # assert position at a word boundary
    (?=lol)        # assert that "lol" can be matched here
    \S*            # match any number of characters except whitespace
    (\S+)          # match at least one character (to be repeated later)
    (?<=\blol)     # until we have reached exactly the position after the 1st "lol"
    \1*            # then repeat the preceding character(s) any number of times
    \b             # and ensure that we end up at another word boundary""", 
    "lol", subject)
```

This will also match the "unadorned" version (i. e. `lol` without any repetition). If you don't want this, use `\1+` instead of `\1*`.